# Openlayers fails to render OSM

Tags: javascript, openlayers, svelte, vite, sveltekit

I'm new to sveltekit. I'm trying to use Openlayers with SvelteKit, and I cannot get the map to render. Here is my map component:

```
<script lang="ts">
    // OpenLayers
    import  Map  from 'ol/Map';
    import TileLayer from 'ol/layer/Tile';

    // Svelte
    import View from 'ol/View';
    import OSM from 'ol/source/OSM';

    // Exports
    let mapId = 20;
    // Local state
    let map = null;

    // functions
    const setupMap = (node, _id) => {
        const osmLayer = new TileLayer({
            source: new OSM()
        })
        map = new Map({
            target: _id,
            layers: [
                osmLayer,
            ],
            view: new View({
                center: [0, 0],
                zoom: 2,
            })
        });
        return {
            destroy() {
                if (map as Map) {
                    map.setTarget(null);
                    map = null;
                }
            }
        }
    }

</script>

<h1>{mapId}</h1>

<div id={mapId} class="map" use:setupMap={mapId}>
</div>

<style>
    .map {
        width: 400px;
        height: 400px;
    }
</style>
```

Here is my +page.svelte:

```
<script>
    // components
    import LDTag from '$lib/components/LDTag.svelte';
    import Map from '$lib/components/Map.svelte';

    // utils
    import { appSchema } from '$lib/utils/json-ld.ts';

</script>

<svelte:head>
    <title>Map</title>
    <meta
        name="description"
        content="Mapping"
    />
</svelte:head>
<LDTag schema={appSchema} />
<h1>Welcome to SvelteKit</h1>
<p>Visit <a href="https://kit.svelte.dev">kit.svelte.dev</a> to read the documentation</p>
<Map/>
```

Here is a screenshot of the page:
[image]

And finally, here is some interesting output from the console:

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: targetElement.appendChild is not a function
    handleTargetChanged_ Map.js:1270
    dispatchEvent Target.js:114
    notify Object.js:176
    set Object.js:215
    setProperties Object.js:229
    Map Map.js:480
    setupMap Map.svelte:32
    mount Map.svelte:75
    m svelte-hooks.js:291
    mount_component index.mjs:1828
    mount +page.svelte:129
    m svelte-hooks.js:291
    mount_component index.mjs:1828
    mount root.svelte:258
    mount layout.svelte:32
    m svelte-hooks.js:291
    mount_component index.mjs:1828
    mount root.svelte:162
    mount root.svelte:458
    mount_component index.mjs:1828
    init index.mjs:1922
    Root root.svelte:623
    createProxiedComponent svelte-hooks.js:341
    ProxyComponent proxy.js:242
    Proxy<Root> proxy.js:349
    initialize client.js:357
    _hydrate client.js:1477
    start start.js:31
    <anonymous> (index):37
Map.js:1270:20
```

Any help will be appreciated, because I have been tearing my hair out over this for hours. Thanks!

Comment: Did you try `target: node` instead of `target: _id`?

Answer (score 0):

I believe something might be wrong with your `_id` variable, maybe it is not a string? Like Corrl suggested, using the reference to the node object directly simplifies things a bit. Here is a working [minimal demo repo](https://github.com/cascading-jox/osm-so-answer) with almost the same code that you have.